# Вместо nbsp появляются знаки вопроса

Tags: php

На сайте есть редактор и при вводе *пробела* он меняется на `nbsp`, при выводе этих данных на страницу вместо *пробела* появляется знак вопроса. В чем может быть проблема? Куда копать?

С редактора идет запись в базу  данных, а с неё выводит на страницу.

В бд записывается знак вопроса nbsp там даже нет

Comment: Больше конкретики: какой редактор? какая кодировка в БД? В самой БД отображаются вопросы или `&nbsp;` ?

Comment: стояла кодировка windows-1251 поменял на .utf-8 ничего не дало. Сайт на самописе.  В БД обычные пробелы

Comment: почитайте вот здесь http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Comment: Это значит что вы не сможете написать PHP исполняемый код т.к. то что в редакторе это статичный HTML который кодируется чтобы предотвратить то самое исполнение.

Comment: Оказывается в БД улетает сразу знак вопроса